# Confusion with the GO statement, uncommitted transactions and alter procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I would like to get to the bottom of this because it's confusing me. Can anyone explain when I should use the GO statement in my scripts?

As I understand it the GO statement is not part of the T-SQL language, instead it is used to send a batch of statements to SQL server for processing.

When I run the following script in Query Analyser it appears to run fine. Then I close the window and it displays a warning:

"There are uncommitted transactions. Do you wish to commit these transactions before closing the window?"

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pvd_sp_job_xxx]
    @jobNum varchar(255)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE tbl_ho_job SET delete='Y' WHERE job = @job;
END


COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

However if I add a GO at the end of the ALTER statement it is OK (as below). How come?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pvd_sp_xxx]
    @jobNum varchar(255)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE tbl_ho_job SET delete='Y' WHERE job = @job;
END
GO


COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

I thought about removing all of the GO's but then it complains that the alter procedure statement must be the first statement inside a query batch? Is this just a requirement that I must adhere to?

It seems odd because if I BEGIN TRANSACTION and GO....that statement is sent to the server for processing and I begin a transaction.

Next comes the ALTER procedure, a COMMIT TRANSACTION and a GO (thus sending those statements to the server for processing with a commit to complete the transaction started earlier), how come it complains when I close the window still? Surely I have satisfied that the alter procedure statement is the first in the batch. How come it complains about are uncommitted transactions.

Any help will be most appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first script, COMMIT is part of the stored procedure...

The BEGIN and END in the stored proc *do not* define the scope (start+finish of the stored proc body): the batch does, which is the next GO (or end of script)

So, changing spacing and adding comments

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO 
--start of batch. This comment is part of the stored proc too
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pvd_sp_job_xxx]
    @jobNum varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN --not needed
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE tbl_ho_job SET delete='Y' WHERE job = @job;
END --not needed
--still in the stored proc
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO--end of batch and stored procedure
```

To check, run

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('dbo.pvd_sp_job_xxx'))
```

Comment: The GO after the first statement BEGIN TRANSACTION also seems redundant.

Comment: Also, as you mentioned that the BEGIN and END does not define scope in stored procedures, the batch does. So I definately need a GO at the end of a CREATE PROCEDURE. So, what's the point of the BEGIN and END?

Comment: Begin and end don't need to be there. The go after begin tran is needed to define the start of batch. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a old post, the question is still in my mind after I compiled one of my procedure successfully without any begin transaction,commit transaction or GO. And the procedure can be called and produce the expected result as well. 
I am working with SQL Server 2012. Does it make some change

I know this is for an answer. But words are too small to notice in comment section.